# Shell is detached automatically from docker container

Tags: docker, apple-m1

I'm using docker to develop something on macOS Apple Silicon M1. (MacMini)

I did follow things.

1. `docker pull` official ubuntu/focal
2. Create image

```
docker create -it --mount type=bind,source=${HOME}/work/dev1,destination=/root/work/dev1 --name dev1 ubuntu:focal /bin/bash
```

3. Create container and attach it

```
docker start -ia dev1
```

After this, I have used this container with coding, running node apps and so on. But, when I keep this attached container without any input for almost 1 hour, it is detached automatically and I am back to macOS shell prompt.

It is not exited. If commmand `docker ps`, the container is still alive.

And if I command `docker attach dev1`, I can continue to interact the shell of the container.

I don't know why it is detached automatically. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it doesn't really answer the questions why and how, it feels to long for comment.

Do you have the same problem if you run the container directly and attach to it with docker exec?

In the 2. step replace `create` with `run`, `-ti` with `-d` to run it detached, and `/bin/bash` with `tail -f /dev/null` so your process 1 blocks and doesn't return immediately.

```
docker run -d --mount type=bind,source=${HOME}/work/dev1,destination=/root/work/dev1 --name dev1 ubuntu:focal tail -f /dev/null

docker exec -ti dev1 bash
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Your advice is useful for me if I cannot find the exact cause. I guess my issue is a kind of bug of docker on macOS M1 version because it is not stable version.